# Unexpected token in angular expression after filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This expression works..

```
"startDate + ' ' + endDate"
```

This also works

```
"startDate | date: mediumDate"
```

This however, gives an error.

```
"startDate | date + ' ' + endDate"
```

Syntax Error: Token '+' is an unexpected token at column 18 of the expression [startDate | date + ' ' + endDate] starting at [+ ' ' + endDate].

Is it possible to continue the expression after the filter?

**EDIT:**

My apologies, I copied the wrong expression.

Comment: I'm just about to update the main answer with details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding parentheses like this:
`"(startDate | date) + ' ' + endDate"`

Comment: Many thanks. I't tried using {{}} but obviously that was wrong. Didn't know you could use normal parentheses that way but it makes sense when you see it.